# setState inside useLayoutEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

As far as I understand it, `useLayoutEffect` runs synchronously, while `useEffect` asynchronously - more or less as if we used `useLayoutEffect`, but with `setTimeout(func,0)`.

`useLayoutEffect` is meant to be used "whenever the effect's changing how the website looks". Therefore, I assume I should use it if, for example, the effect changes some state that's then later displayed to the user.

However, `setState` itself is asynchronous, which seems to defeat the synchronous purpose of `useLayoutEffect` - the UI change will be reflected in the DOM only in the next tick (unless we mutate the DOM directly, in an non-Reactish way).

What do I not understand correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useLayoutEffect` is meant to be used in cases where we need to read/write something from the DOM before that cycle is painted in the browser.

As you point, `setState` will update the value and trigger a new cycle, after the browser has been painted. Depending on the use of `setState` it might make sense to include it inside a `useEffect` or `useLayoutEffect`. For example if we were setting a value that we needed to read from the DOM before that cycle renders then it could make sense `setState($ref.current.some_value_before_DOM_updates)`.

Comment: Do we have the guarantee that there won't be a repaint before the next state is applied? After all, setState is synchronous.

Comment: @Kinara, what I mean is that the DOM property value is read before it is painted, the property has changed but the user can't see it yet. We use this value present in the DOM but not visible yet, as the new state value, but this change/update of state will always be applied in the next render (next paint too).

Comment: If I understand it correctly, using setState within an useLayoutEffect will trigger a new render phase, but all is done synchronously (even all useEffects are flushed). So both render phases are done before the paint may occure. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17334#issuecomment-553984285

Answer (score 2):

`setState` is asynchronous as you have mentioned. And for another fact, it triggers react to **re-render**.
However, **note** that inside a *layout effect*(i.e `useLayoutEffect`), when you schedule a re-render, the **browser won't paint until it calculates layout** (for you to read measurements or apply latest changes to an element). Hence re-render scheduled by `useLayoutEffect` is **synchronous;** blocking the visualization until layout changes have been calculated.

Unlike the `useLayoutEffect`, re-renders scheduled inside `useEffect` will let the browser to paint. And **thereafter**, the browser will calculate the layout from your latest changes and paint in the next frame. This will usually result in user seeing a flush of dispositioned/unstyled element before it is fixed in the next frame.

Another important note is that, in the event of synchronous render, react also flushes the remaining/pending effects that would otherwise run in a later frame.